# Detect and extract head from body contour opencv

Tags: opencv, tracking, detection, contour, head

Having the contour of a human body (as in the link below), I want to detect and track the head only. I have tried fitting an elipse to the top third of the bounding box but no good results. Any ideas for a robust approach.
Many thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUsHl.jpg

Comment: What about training a Viola & Jones detector using the contours (instead the traditional usage of gray-scale images)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fit the omega-shape, it will be much more robust.